# Deploy contract in web3j quorum problem

Tags: contract-deployment, web3j, quorum

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract (7 nodes sample from Quorum) using web3j.
It fails at get() to get the contract wrapper object. If I check the logs, a new transaction will show up, but if I call any contract function, it will give me a null pointer exception. My code looks like this:

```
    String deployeraccount = "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d";
    String privfor = "QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=";

    try {

        Quorum quorum = Quorum.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:22000"));

        ClientTransactionManager transactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(
                quorum, deployeraccount, Arrays.asList(privfor));

        BigInteger gasPrice = BigInteger.valueOf(30000);
        BigInteger gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(100000); 
        BigInteger initialWeiValue = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        Uint256 initVal = new Uint256(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

        System.out.println(">> Before deploy");

        Future<Simplestorage> ft = Simplestorage.deploy(    quorum, 
                                                            transactionManager, 
                                                            gasPrice, 
                                                            gasLimit, 
                                                            initialWeiValue, 
                                                            initVal     );
        System.out.println(">> deploy");

        while (!ft.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        System.out.println(">> after wait");

        Simplestorage ss = ft.get();
```

I already tried changing the gas value, but still got the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I used the default wrapperobject.GAS_PRICE and wrapperobject.GAS_LIMIT. Now it works.

Comment: Could you create an answer adding a few more details of what you did? Comments shouldn't be relied on to exist forever, and if you add an answer it may get some upvotes :-)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I added that thin information as an answer. I did make it a community wiki though, as I didn't feel comfortable getting credit for an answer that wasn't mine. Plus a community wiki allows people to enhance it.

Comment: This implementation now is deprecated with the quorum 4.0.6v. Do you update de Web3j quorum version??

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a community wiki from the author's own response in a comment. Let's improve on it.*

I used the default `wrapperobject.GAS_PRICE` and `wrapperobject.GAS_LIMIT`. Now it works.